# How do I install BigArtm on Windows?

Tags: python

There is a link to install `BigArtm` on https://bigartm.readthedocs.io/en/v0.8.0/download.html, but it just doesn't work. I have tried to install it by pip and it gave me an error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bigartm (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for bigartm
```

I now use `python39`, but I also tried same step with `python38` and `python37`. Nothing works. Maybe there is another way of installing `BigArtm`?
Thank you!!!

Comment: Unfortuantely this is a dead project and installation on Windows is very very poorly documented. I wish there was a replacement that actually works, but none that I'm aware of at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The error you provide is not so much to do with it. The BigARTM library isn't support for long time.

If you need to install it (for some cases), I recommend you to user Google Colab for this purpose.

Here is [Example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Tr1ZO03iPufj11HtIH3JjaWWU1Wyxkzv) of working notebook for this purpose. This code work up for python 3.10 (or below).

```
!cd /content && git clone --branch=stable https://github.com/bigartm/bigartm.git
!cd /content/bigartm && mkdir build
!cd /content/bigartm/build && cmake -DPYTHON=python3 ..
!cd /content/bigartm/build && make
!cd /content/bigartm/build && sudo make install
!export ARTM_SHARED_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libartm.so
!cd /content/bigartm/python && python setup.py install
```

Then **restart** your colab environment (Environment -> Restart environment) and import this library:

```
import artm
```

... or you can provide additional info about the error. I remember I have some several trouble with wheel (and it was connected with google library...) but I can't find it, sorry.